# JQuery selector returns the same class

Tags: jquery, html, django

I have written a dynamic page that loads the products from the context object. the number of products in the object, number of times the loop will run and I have created a hidden input. in each iteration, the value of hidden input will be the primary key of the product. but when I use jquery to fetch the value of clicked product, the id of first product is returned. Any product I click only the first products id is been returned.

```
{% for album in list1 %}

<div class="col-lg-3"  id="div1">
<div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
<input type="hidden" class="custId"  value={{ album.id }}>
```

{{ album.product_name }}
      Category : {{ album.product_category }}

Price : {{album.id  }}

```
$('.k').click(function(){
        var a  = $('.custId').val();
        alert(a);

        console.log(a)

    });
```

Comment: html code --
{% for album in list1 %}
 <div class="col-lg-3"  id="div1"> <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;"> <input type="hidden" class="custId"  value={{ album.id }}><div class="card-body"><a href="#" class="k"><imgsrc=e646c987b3dcf11c9329af5070847f92.wclass="card-img-top" alt="..." height="90px" width="85px" ></a><h5 class="card-title" value="{{ album.id }}"> {{ album.product_name }}</h5<p class="card-text" id="{{album.id}}">Category : {{ album.product_category }}</p> <p class="card-text" >Price : {{album.id  }}</p></div></div></div>  {% endfor %}

Comment: Access using `var a = $(this).parents('.card').find('.custId').val()`

Comment: Reason is you are accessing value using class which gets the array of elements having class k and returns first value i.e. of very products so you need to specify to get clicked product id.

Answer (score 0):

The query `$('.customId')` returns all hidden inputs in the page. Try this instead

```
$(this).closest('.card').find('.customId').val();
```

In the context of the click event `this` is the clicked link.

You could also use the data attributes instead of a hidden input

```
<a href="#" class="k" data-customId="{{album.id}}"><img/></a>
```

and then in javascript

```
$(this).data('customId');
```